# SP 2010 Toolbar URL link button becomes inactive after multiple uses

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, toolbar

When editing pages in SharePoint 2010 if our editors use the URL Link option in the toolbar on a page they can make sporadic links in the page with no problem, often doing Links from Address or Links from SharePoint once or twice on a page is fine.  With multiple edits, in the same session where the page is still in edit mode and not saved, the Link to Address option is available but trying to use it the pop-up never appears.  Used once or twice in a session, no problem, more than that and often the option won't activate, the pull down will show the Address option as highlighted but it won't bring up the pop-up to allow creation of the link.

Often the only way to get this back is to close out the edit session, clear the cache in the browser then go back and edit the page.  This happens more with the Address option than the SharePoint link option, if the Link to Address option becomes unavailble the Link to SharePoint option is still active and can be selected.

In checking with Fiddler I see that a use to the Link tool generates a call to: `_layouts/RteDialog.aspx?LCID=1033&Dialog=CreateLink&UseDivDialog=true&IsDlg=1`

When the problem occurs and the options become unavailable there is just no call, so it seems that either the browser just doesn't know what to do or the call back to SharePoint is bogged down somehow but I am not sure where to look.

We are using SP2010 Enterprise, this happens with IE8 and we want our editors to use IE8 to eliminate issues so while I could say there is an option to use FireFox we'd like to standardize.  Has anyone seen similar issues with Toolbar options and have an idea where I can troubleshoot further?

Comment: First of all, you should check the page for js errors. In IE8, the most accurate way to do this is to open developer tools (F12), and start page debugging, and see if something will show up.

Comment: Never noticed any before when I did a profile, I will try and replicate again and see if I can find something.

Comment: We are currently facing the same issue with a few users but unfortunately, we can't reproduce it at our site. Have you found a solution for this problem or know why it is happening? I appreciate any help!

Comment: Sadly no, far as I can even guess at this point is that it is some sort of JavaScript failure.  It's very repeatable on the one person who does this alot and I can get it to happen if I spend some time editing pages and utilize the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue, and have found a workaround that works 'some times'.
If your link is multiple words, try highlighting just one of the words, click Link > To address and see if you get the popup.  If so, then go back and select all the words and try Link > To address again. I can get this way to work about 50% of the time. Very frustrating to say the least.
Here is another post that says

tags are the issue. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/fa195512-0bfc-4d83-be62-34ebc0f8a443